# java.lang.NullPointerException thrown

Tags: java

How do I catch the null that is thrown if the file object returns `null`? I keep getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
public static File getFile() {
        String filePath = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the full path to           the file you want to open");
        File file = new File(filePath);
        while(!file.exists()) {
            filePath = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a valid full path");
        }
        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should format your code in a readable format

Comment: you need to create the file right? if it doesn't exist

Comment: To answer your question: [TryCatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html). However this is really not how you want to handle it. You probably want to check against `null` with a simple `if`.

Comment: Note that your `while` loop is bad, since it never changes `file`, so it'll loop forever if the first input is a non-existent file.

Comment: Yeah if the file is valid I need to return the file

Answer (score 0):

javadocs about `public File(String pathname)` constructor:

```
NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null
```

so better check `filePath` is not `null`, before passing it to `new File(String path)`